# C++ library with array operations similar to Python/NumPy

Tags: python, c++, arrays, numpy

Please excuse for asking possibly a too broad question. However, my task is very concrete: having not much experience with Python, I want to rewrite Python code to C++ (OpenCV) and I wonder if there is a good documented comparison for some C++ library (I know that there exist OpenBLAS, Eigen, etc.) that would allow me relatively easily repeat all the array operations made in original code which turns to be quite a challenge for me using OpenCV. Maybe some one actually wrote posts about syntax comparison?

Python code:

```
image = im_orig.copy()
# Create input for multiples of net input/output changes.
im_bg_width = int(_np.ceil(
    float(image.shape[1]) * scale_factor / _STRIDE) * _STRIDE)
im_bg_height = int(_np.ceil(
    float(image.shape[0]) * scale_factor / _STRIDE) * _STRIDE)
pad_size = 64
im_bot_pixels = image[-1:, :, :]
im_bot = _np.tile(im_bot_pixels, (pad_size, 1, 1))
image = _np.vstack((image, im_bot))
im_right_pixels = image[:, -1:, :]
im_right = _np.tile(im_right_pixels, (1, pad_size, 1))
image = _np.hstack((image, im_right))
image = _scipy.misc.imresize(image, scale_factor, interp='bilinear')
image = image.astype('float32') - _MEAN

net_input = _np.zeros((im_bg_height, im_bg_width, 3), dtype='float32')
net_input[:min(net_input.shape[0], image.shape[0]),
          :min(net_input.shape[1], image.shape[1]), :] =\
    image[:min(net_input.shape[0], image.shape[0]),
          :min(net_input.shape[1], image.shape[1]), :]
```

EDIT: I want to get rid of python dependecy (and especially from python C++ API) at any cost and have the program actually readable, unlike what Cython produces.

Comment: You probably want to search for a C++ numeric library, but note that if you are rewriting the code in C++ to improve the performance, you could be disappointed—good NumPy code tends to be very fast to begin with.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Thanks, I know that NumPy is fast, but getting rid of Python at any cost is essential.

Comment: "At any cost" shouldn't be in an engineer's vocabulary :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Eigen is probably suitable for you. If you have not tried it (i don't know based on your question), you should take a look at it. Apart from being very fast (amongst the fasterst, from what i've gathered), it has also a pretty natural syntax. It does not get much better, if C++ only is concerned.

http://eigen.tuxfamily.org

Comment: Thanks! No, I have experience with OpenCV only. Maybe there are some hints somewhere about rewriting between Eigen and NumPy to start with? I understand that it sounds a bit lazy, but it becomes very hard and time-consuming to switch from one solution to another

Comment: You know what your original code is about, right? What it does, mathematically speaking? Then you can start here: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMatrixClass.html It starts by explaining basic matrix/linear algebra stuff....

Comment: As for direct rewrite instructions: I don't think such a thing exists, nor would it be very useful in general. But in general there should be an equivalent or at least very similar operation in the Eigen library for everything numpy can do.

Comment: Ok, as long as there is an equivalent, I'll try it. Thank you!